# Use of unresolved identifier 'present' in Swift (Apple tutorial)

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction, presentviewcontroller

I'm just following the official Apple introduction tutorial for Swift and Xcode by making a FoodTracker app.
I've got this error (see title).

This is Xcode 7.2.1
I have imported UIKit

Here's the code I have where the issue appears. I have all class protocols and delegates and everything.

```
  @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their library.
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I would appreciate any help since I just started learning this language!

Comment: which xcode / swift version are you using?

Comment: What class is this `func` delcared in?  Is it a `UIViewController` or subclass thereof?

Comment: 7.2.1 @AndréSlotta

Comment: Yes UIViewController @i_am_jorf

Comment: I have this already @sasquatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case (you are using xcode 7 -> swift 2) it has to be:

```
presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

right now you are using swift3 syntax.

Comment: This is it, thank you! Switching to a higher xcode now ;)

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added your class to your current target. You can confirm it by right pane beside your code editor or storyboard whatever is open in your canvas! You can confirm it from 'file inspector'. Check 'membership targets' check the checkbox of current target to add your class to it if it is unchecked!

Comment: The class is just UIViewController and the checkbox of the name of the app is checked. This is what you meant right?